# Outllok add in REST call: RequestBroker-ParseUri -- "Resource not found for the segment 'messages'."

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

I followed this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api, and receive an error on rest api call:

```
{"error":{"code":"RequestBroker-ParseUri","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'messages'."}}
```

Token and message ID have correct values, code is from docs, the only thing I did replace is `Office.context.mailbox.restUrl` for default  `https://outlook.office.com` since first one is empty for me (why?)

Actually code:

```
function getItemRestId() {
    // Currently the only Outlook Mobile version that supports add-ins
    // is Outlook for iOS.
    if (Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === 'OutlookIOS') {
        // itemId is already REST-formatted
        return Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
    } else {
      // Convert to an item ID for API v2.0
        return Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
            Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
            Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0
      );
    }
}

function getCurrentItem(accessToken) {
    var itemId = getItemRestId();
    var getMessageUrl = 'https://outlook.office.com' +
      '/api/v2.0/messages/' + itemId;

  $.ajax({
      url: getMessageUrl,
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
  }).done(function(item){
      var subject = item.Subject;
  }).fail(function(error){
      // log error is here 
  });
}

Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, function(result){
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
        var accessToken = result.value;
        // Use the access token
      getCurrentItem(accessToken);
      } else {
        // Handle the error
      }
});
```

What I did wrong? Do you think it's because I replaced `restUrl` value? I do use custom domain email.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Could anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.

i used

```
var getMessageUrl = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/'+ itemId+"/attachments";
```

instead of below url:

```
var getMessageUrl = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/messages/' + itemId;
```

API gives proper response after using the first API.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not getting a value from the restUrl property, I suspect you're using an on-prem Exchange Server. This is a [known issue](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5#resturl-string) with on-prem installations. This is also why using the `https://outlook.office.com` won't work (you're server isn't located at that URI).

You might be able to get around this using the [Hybrid Deployment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support) configuration. This allows you to execute Microsoft Graph API calls against a local server. That said, I have **not tried this** so it may not work in this scenario. Given that all of these components (1.5 and Hybrid) are in Preview, unexpected results should always be expected.